# How to send integer value in WinPcap?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, winpcap

I set mac addresses and practised the WinPcap's tutorial as in this link:
https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut8.html (Sending a single packet with pcap_sendpacket() title)

However, I need to add 9999 value to 25th index as the below.

```
packet[25]=9999;
```

But the packet has to be `u_char` type. How can I assign the variable as I want in this case?

Comment: In that example, `packet` is, as you say, `u_char`. That means it can only contain values in the range (0 - 255). Hence it makes no sense to set one of those values to 9999. What is it you're actually intending to accomplish?

Comment: @GilHamilton I need to send integer values inside of packet. How can I do it then?

Answer (score 0):

The value 9999 is larger than 255 so it can't fit into 1 byte. You need 2 bytes to write it. So let's say you can use bytes 25 and 26. In that case you need the following code:

```
#include <winsock2.h> // for using ntohs
...
*(uint16_t*)(packet + 25) = htons(9999);
```

The need in `htons` is for writing the value in network order